# CSS Transparent Gold Background

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling for days on how to achieve this transparent gold at the right side of the image below. [image]

That is what exactly look like in the PSD but when saving it as .PNG it seems to look like a very different color as it kinda turns to yellow. Maybe because it doesn't use the web standard colors. So I'm trying some CSS solution on this code sample below, but I don't know how to do it right or what should be the color combination should I use.

```css
.bg-gold { position: relative; }
.bg-gold-1, .bg-gold-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
.bg-gold-1 {
  background: #b38600;
  opacity: .5;
}
.bg-gold-2 {
  background: #b36b00;
  opacity: .2;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-gold">
  <img src="http://wilsin.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/index-banner-1-black-and-white.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="bg-gold bg-gold-1"></div>
  <div class="bg-gold bg-gold-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your question, how to create the shapes?

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly, you should look into CSS blend modes. Heres a link https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Comment: @ovokuro, not the shape but the transparent background. I can work with the shape as long as I resolved the background.

Comment: @k.cornett, I will look into it. Will get back to you my update.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve using css property transform.Hope this code helps.

```css
.infoContainer {
  margin: 30px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  position:relative;

  /* non-essential styling */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  background-color:rgba(218,165,32,0.5);
}

.infoContainerB {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  position:relative;

  /* non-essential styling */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  background-color:rgba(218,165,32,0.8);
}

.infoContainer p,
.infoContainerB p {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
}

.wrapper {
  font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, Sans;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <figure>
    <div class="infoContainer">
      <p>Howdy!!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoContainerB">
      <p>Howdy B!!</p>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: It might be helpful to show a different background in your code snippet so the op can see the transparency in action.

Comment: That's very useful.! But the problem is, I don't know how to match that exact transparent gold background from my attached image(right side).

Maybe I'll have to look at the css blend mode first which mentioned by @k.cornett. And maybe will combine with your code if possible. Thank you so far.

Comment: Hi @karthnik, can you please help me with all the text inside these 3 boxes on this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/randzgonz02/5orouccL/6/? Because it seems that the text inside them are affected and cannot be read easily. I want to display them properly like what we can see from above sample image I uploaded. Do you think it's possible to do this way?

Answer (score 1):

Using an appropriate value of `mix-blend-mode` on your overlay should do the trick; you can read more about all the values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).

Based on playing around a bit, I think `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` should work well, but you'll need to play around a bit to get the desired effect.

Keep in mind [browser support is varied](https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode)